# Як правильно: “з'їзджання„ або “з'їжджання„?

Tags: орфографія

Як правильно писати: „зїзджання“, „зїжджання“, „з'їзджання“ або „з'їжджання“?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

З словником правильно «**з'їжджа́ти**», «**з'їжджа́ння**» ([словник УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/): «[з'їжджа́ти](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B7'%D1%97%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)», «[з'їжджа́ння](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B7'%D1%97%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)»; [словники R2U](//r2u.org.ua): «[з'їжджа́ти](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7'%D1%97%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)», «[з'їжджа́ння](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7'%D1%97%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)»; [тлумачний словник в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/): «[з'їжджа́ти](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=36410&page=1149)», «[з'їжджа́ння](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=199165&page=1149)»; [тлумачний словник в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/): «[з'їжджа́ти](http://sum.in.ua/s/z.jizhdzhaty)»).

Апостроф між приголосною і «ї» ставиться завжди. Щодо «„зд“ чи „ждж“» — маємо чергування: в різних словах чи навіть формах із цим коренем маємо різні літери, наприклад, в доконанних формах дієслова часто більш усталилося «зд» («з'ї́**зд**ити») чи «х» («з'ї́**х**ати»), а в недоконаних — «ждж» («з'ї**ждж**а́ти»); хоча це не завжди так, наприклад, для доконаного «приї́**х**ати» є два недоконані варіанти «приї**ждж**а́ти»=«приї**зд**и́ти».

Такі прості питання в подальшому слід спочатку самому перевіряти за словником — і питати лише в тому випадку, якщо виникли якісь складнощі, наприклад, різні словники пропонують різне написання.